# How to enable sourcemaps with grunt, browserify, and babelify

Tags: browserify, grunt-browserify

I'd like to generate sourcemaps for jsx files that are transpiled with babelify and browserify. It seems that some sourcemaps are being generated as a base64 encoded comment at the bottom of my output file, but stacktraces do not honor them.

My grunt task looks like the following:

```
browserify: {
  options: {
    browserifyOptions: {
      debug: true
    },
    debug: true,
    transform: ['babelify']
  },
  app: {
    src: 'src/app.jsx',
    dest: 'dist/app.js'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
browserify: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
                debug: true
            },
            transform: [["babelify"]]
        },
        files: {
            "dist/bundle.js": "src/index.js"
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Going to need to use [grunt-exorcise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exorcise) to extract the map from the bundle.

[Browserify recommends it](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-source-maps)

```
browserify: {
  options: {
    browserifyOptions: {
      debug: true
    },
    debug: true,
    transform: ['babelify']
  },
  app: {
    src: 'src/app.jsx',
    dest: 'dist/app.js'
  }
},
exorcise: {
    app: {
       options: {},
       files: {
          'dist/app.js.map':['dist/app.js'],
       }
    }
},
```